# Boto3 S3 NosuchKey error when downloading file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, boto

I am accessing the Project Gutenberg API and I wrote a Python program that creates a text file out of a randomly chosen book from the API. Since the txt file is  different each time the document in the S3 bucket should be blank. I want to be able to store an object I can constantly write over in S3 then pull from it in Flask and put it on the user's computer.

So far I have been using boto3 and I set up an AWS account with a specific bucket. I loaded a trial .txt file in there but when the program is accessed now it only downloads the file I put in there with the specific text, it doesn't change based on my program like it should.

Boto seems to be throwing me for a loop so if there's another way I am open to it.

My code right now is a mess. I'm throwing everything I can at it to make it work but I know I've reach the point where I need some help.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from gutenberg.acquire import load_etext
from gutenberg.cleanup import strip_headers
import random
import os 
from flask import send_from_directory
import boto3
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import Flask, Response
from boto3 import client
import botocore



app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')


def get_client():
    return client(
        's3',
        'us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXX',
        aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXX'
    )


@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return 'Welcome to the server'


@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/roulette', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def roulette():
    s3 = get_client()
    f = open("GutProject.txt", "w")
    file = s3.get_object(Bucket='book-roulette', Key='GutProject.txt')
    for x in range(1):
        y = (random.randint(0, 59000))
        text = strip_headers(load_etext(y)).strip()
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        open('GutProject.txt').write(text)
        s3_client.upload_file('GutProject.txt', 'book-roulette', 'Gut-remote.txt')
        s3_client.download_file('book-roulette', 'hello-remote.txt', 'hello2.txt')
        print(open('hello2.txt').read())s3_client.download_file('MyBucket', 'hello-remote.txt', 'hello2.txt')
        print(open('hello2.txt').read())
        return Response(
        file['Body'].read(),
        mimetype='text/plain',
        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=GutProject.txt"}
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My app should let the user click a button on the URL page and it will download a random file to their computer. The HTML works great and the Python/Flask worked before but the file wasn't downloading (I'm on Heroku).

I keep getting these errors:

botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey

botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.

Comment: can you post the full traceback for your error?

Comment: I'm still kind of new, the full traceback is really long can you recommend a way for me to post on here? I keep saying it's like 1574 characters too long.

Answer (score 1):

If the error stems from the line: `s3_client.download_file('book-roulette', 'hello-remote.txt', 'hello2.txt')`, then the error NoSuchKey is trying to say it cannot find the file `s3://book-roulette/hello-remote.txt` in the s3 region you specify.

I would suggest checking that s3 path to make sure it exists, or that the specified bucket and key are correct.

Edit: I notice that you create the `s3_client` object within your loop and overwrite the one where you specify your region and credentials, so it's possible it might not be checking in the right region anymore, but that might result in an access denied error or bucket not found error instead

Comment: I'm betting you're right. My question is, is it possible to create a key from the program or do I have to do it in AWS? Because the file needs to be constantly written over if I load a file in there I'm worries it will keep generating the same file over and over again. I tried that once and had that result.

Comment: The key is the rest of the path onward from the bucket up to and including the file name and extension.
For example, if your file is in `s3://my-bucket/some_folder/file.txt`, then the bucket would be `my-bucket` and the key would be `some_folder/file.txt`.
Uploading a file to s3 using boto3 will create the necessary path for you, and if the file already exists then it will be overwritten.

Comment: if `my-bucket` was empty and I set the upload key to `some_folder/file.txt`, it would create `some_folder` for me and put it in. Thus it is possible to create the key in your program.

Comment: @JordanBrandes creating an object using SDK and using web portal are the same thing. Web browser is a wrapper for the API, which the SDK uses. I agree with @Farrago-Alex it could be that when you declare `s3_client` in your for loop, you're using a different region.

Comment: A bit of an update. I have actually managed to upload to the S3 button and it does re-write whenever I run the program. Now I just need to download that file to the user's computer.